# Does $_schema get inherited in Lithium parent & child Model?

Tags: php, inheritance, lithium

We all know that functions are inherited, but how about the protected `$_schema` of Lithium Model?

For example, I have:

```
class ParentModel extends Model {
   protected $_schema = array(
     'name' => array('type' => 'string'),
     'address' => array('type' => 'string'),
    );
}

class ChildModel extends ParentModel {
    protected $_schema = array(
        'mobile' => array('type' => 'string'),
        'email' => array('type' => 'string'),
    );
}
```

I wonder when saving a `ChildModel` record, would the `$_schema` of `ChildModel`   combined with the `$_schema` of `ParentModel`? That's:

```
array(
    'name' => array('type' => 'string'),
    'address' => array('type' => 'string'),
    'mobile' => array('type' => 'string'),
    'email' => array('type' => 'string'),
);
```

How can I check if this is the case?

Big Thanks

Comment: No, it wont combine. You are overriding the property in Child class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically in PHP, variables defined this way will override the parent class' default value for the same class. However, Lithium models [have code](http://li3.me/docs/lithium/data/Model::_inherit()) that iterates through parents and merges in their defaults for `$_schema` and all other variables listed in `$_inherits` and the defaults returned by `Model::_inherited()`.

Here is [the code](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/1.0-beta/data/Model.php#L444-L493) for this in the 1.0-beta release

```
/**
 * Merge parent class attributes to the current instance.
 */
protected function _inherit() {
    $inherited = array_fill_keys($this->_inherited(), array());
    foreach (static::_parents() as $parent) {
        $parentConfig = get_class_vars($parent);
        foreach ($inherited as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($parentConfig["{$key}"])) {
                $val = $parentConfig["{$key}"];
                if (is_array($val)) {
                    $inherited[$key] += $val;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($parent === __CLASS__) {
            break;
        }
    }
    foreach ($inherited as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($this->{$key})) {
            $this->{$key} += $value;
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Return inherited attributes.
 *
 * @param array
 */
protected function _inherited() {
    return array_merge($this->_inherits, array(
        'validates',
        'belongsTo',
        'hasMany',
        'hasOne',
        '_meta',
        '_finders',
        '_query',
        '_schema',
        '_classes',
        '_initializers'
    ));
}
```

Here are some of the unit tests that cover this functionality: https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/1.0-beta/tests/cases/data/ModelTest.php#L211-L271

Answer (score 0):

As answered on the github issue that you opened, yes.